# React Redux, rerendering after data was fetched and mapped into component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hi I am having trouble with getting data fetched and available as this.props.data to pass into a child component `<GoogleMaps />` and rerendering when the data has changed.

It only works the first time the form is submitted and data is fetched but not again. The new data is not available since the `render()` function calls `{this.renderMap(this.props.data)}` before `{this.renderData()}`, which fetches and returns and maps the data.

I tried switching them but it looks like the render() function is not waiting until data is fetched before calling `{this.renderMap(this.props.data)}`. Should I be passing the data to the GoogleMap component a different way that allows it to reload with new data before rendering?

My renderData(); works fine, which returns component `ListItem`. It works every time my form is submitted. The problem is getting `GoogleMaps` component to be aware of this change and re-rendering?

```
class Feature extends Component {

    handleFormSubmit({ term, location }) {
        this.props.fetchData( { term, location });
        this.setState({showMap: true});
    }
    renderData() {
        return this.props.data.map((data) => {
            return (
                <ListItem
                    key={data.id}
                    data={data} />
            )
        });
    }
    renderMap(data) {
        if (this.state.showMap == true) {
            const lon = data[0].location.coordinate.longitude;
            const lat = data[0].location.coordinate.latitude;
        return (
            <GoogleMap 
               data={data} 
               lon={lon} 
               lat={lat} />
        )
        }
    }
    render() {
        const { handleSubmit, fields: { term, location }} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
                        <fieldset className="form-group">
                            <label>Find:</label>
                            <input className="form-control" {...term} />
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset className="form-group">
                            <label>Location:</label>
                            <input className="form-control" {...location} />
                        </fieldset>
                        <button action="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className="map_container">
                {this.renderMap(this.props.data)}
                </div>
                <ul className="list-group">
                {this.renderData()}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { data: state.data };
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'search',
    fields: ['term', 'location']
}, mapStateToProps, actions)(Feature);
```

Here is the fetchData function, I am getting the data fine.

```
export function fetchData( {term, location} ) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/data`, {term, location})
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({ 
                type: FETCH_DATA,
                payload: response 
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us `fetchData()` function?

Answer (score 2):

Finally solved this. `ComponentsWillReceiveProps` did the trick. Had to call `ComponentsWillReceiveProps` with `nextProps` and call `setState` to set the data to `nextProps.data`.

This allowed me to use the data to render the `GoogleMaps` lat long coordinates and set each marker.

Comment: This looks like a bad idea, you should not fill your `state` with stuff from `props`

Answer (score 0):

Using ComponentsWillReceiveProps and passing your props to a component's state is rarely a good idea. Could you show us your reducer code? Perhaps you are mutating your state which can result in components not re-rendering when you expect them to.

Also, you shouldn't need to pass your props though to renderMap `{this.renderMap(this.props.data)}`. renderMap has access to this.props by default.